# window.open post param to servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets

i have a new question, i want to pass some param using post and window.open, my code is the next:

```
     document.form1.INFCENTRO.value=9991;
     document.form1.NOMBRENTI.value='DOCALIA';
     document.form1.NOMBRENTI.disabled=true;
     document.form1.NOMAPE.disabled=true;
     document.form1.CLAVEUSU.value=user_espe;
     document.form1.CLAVEUSU.disabled=true;
     document.form1.FECHAPETI.disabled=true;

    function redireccionar() {

    window.open("http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTipoPapel",'_parent');

     }

    setTimeout(redireccionar, 20);
```

how can i pass that params to my Servlet? The param are obtain using fex, but that is a process that i can not changed.

Thanks.

Comment: If you just want the form contents to be send to the parent window, then you don't need window.open - just give the form a target attribute.

Comment: the problem is that my servlet calls EXTjs where i work with a database, with window.open i send the param to the servlet that then do a consult with the param that i recive from the fex and my param. thats the problem.. i cannot chagend the fex, and for example with window.open i can put my app in the frame of the web pages originally